# How to make .contains search for every string in an array?

Tags: android

I have this code :

```
String[] whereyoufromarray = {"where", "you", "from"};

for (String whereyoufromstring : whereyoufromarray)
{
    if (value.contains(whereyoufromstring)) {
        //statement
    }
}
```

But I want that if to only execute the statement if "value" has all of the words included in the array, something like "where are you from?". Currently if value has ONLY one of the words in the array the statement is executed.

I can do this with `if (value.contains("where") && value.contains("you") && value.contains ("from"))` but this just seems unnecessarily long. There has to be a workaround using arrays that I am missing.

Well, what is it?

p.s.: sorry for poor grammar. i'm suffering from sleep deprivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] whereyoufromarray = {"where", "you", "from"};

boolean valueContainsAllWordsInArray = true;
for (String whereyoufromstring : whereyoufromarray) {

    // If one word wasn't found, the search is over, break the loop
    if(!valueContainsAllWordsInArray) break;

    valueContainsAllWordsInArray = valueContainsAllWordsInArray &&
                                   value.contains(whereyoufromstring);

}

// valueContainsAllWordsInArray is now assigned to true only if value contains
// ALL strings in the array
```

Comment: This is nice and simple, but I feel like we should at least break out of the loop if no extra work needs to be done.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Good call! I have added this optimization.

Comment: Maybe I'm being too cautious, but I don't like the fact that we're altering the state of `valueContainsAllWordsInArray` every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @user2471760 I'm glad it helped :) Maybe accept the answer if it was the most helpful for you?

Comment: @Kevin I don't see why this assignment is a problem if it is logically correct. That doesn't take any extra time to do. Edward Falk's answer is great and does essentially the same thing, just abstracted into a method. In practice, that is cleaner and I like his answer, but I just wanted to solve OP's problem in place exactly as described without any additional abstractions.

Answer (score 2):

For a case like this, I typically implement a function just to make the test. Let's call it *containsAll()*

```
public static boolean containsAll(String[] strings, String test)
{
    for (String str : strings)
        if (!test.contains(str))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

And now you just do

```
if (containsAll(whereyoufromarray, value))
    //statement
```

Comment: I think this is the best way. Perhaps even put it into an extension method if it were in C#.

Comment: Looks good, but if test is null, then you should return false immediately before the the `for`. Same for if `strings.length == 0`

Comment: True. Obviously, I omitted those details as an exercise for the reader

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] whereyoufromarray = {"where", "you", "from"};
 int arrayLength = whereyoufromarray.length;
 int itemCount = 0;
 for(String whereyoufromstring : whereyoufromarray)
 {
    if(value.contains(whereyoufromstring))
    {
        itemCount++; 
    }
 }
 if (itemCount == arrayLength){
    //do your thing here   
 }
```

rough idea.  I don't have my IDE up to proof this, but basically you can set a counter to = the length of your known array, then check each value in the array to see if it contains a match..if it does, increment another counter.  At the end, test your counter to see if it matches the length of your array, so in your example, if itemCount= 3, then all values matched.  if it was 2, then one would be missing and your method wouldn't execute.